# Selecting factors based upon distance between two rows in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to select the ids from the data frame below that have values of 2 in the num column that are *at least* 2 rows apart. In other words, given the following data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                 num=c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2))
df2$id <- as.factor(df2$id)
```

How can I select the id variables such that values of 2 are separated by *at least* one row?

The result of the procedure I am seeking would select id 1, since the values of 2 are separated by at least one row (2 rows in this example). Thanks.

Also, the solution below doesn't seem to work on the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),
  num=c(1,2,1, 1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2,1, 1,1,1,2,2,1, 1,2,1,2,2,2)
)     
df$id<-as.factor(df$id)
```

Again, the result should be only id 1. I just want to find, per ID, any instances where the number 2 is separated by another 2 by one or more rows.

Comment: What's the expected output for the second example?

Comment: the same as the first one.  I just want to find, per ID, any instances where the number 2 is separated by another 2 by one or more rows.

Comment: Ok. Generally, it is best to be explicit about such a requirement from the start. I read it as "all values" instead of "any values" since you had not specified it. I think the modified answer might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**data.table** I would use the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[num == 2, .N > 1L && any(diff(.I) > 2L), by=id]

   id    V1
1:  1  TRUE
2:  2 FALSE
3:  3 FALSE
```

*How it works:* The syntax is `DT[i, j, by]`

- `i` subsets rows
- then `by` groups the remaining rows
- then `j` is computed

Inside `j` we have `.I`, which stores row number for convenience; and `.N`, the number of rows in the `by` group. So to extract the ids have `V1 == TRUE`, we can do `res[V1 == TRUE, id]`. Alternately, the whole operation can be chained like

```
df[num == 2, .N > 1L && any(diff(.I) > 2L), by=id][V1 == TRUE, id]

[1] 1
Levels: 1 2 3
```

---

**base or dplyr** The (almost) analogue in base R is

```
sapply(split(df$num == 2, df$id), function(x){
  w = which(x)
  length(w) > 1L && any(diff(w) > 2L) 
})

    1     2     3 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The latter also works in dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(x = {
  w = which(num == 2)
  length(w) > 1L && any(diff(w) > 2L) 
})

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      id     x
  <fctr> <lgl>
1      1  TRUE
2      2 FALSE
3      3 FALSE
```

Comment: Can your solution be generalized if the data frame is of the following form:               df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),num=c(1,2,1,1,2,2,  1,1,1,2,2,1, 1,1,1,2,2,1, 1,2,1,2,2,2))
     df$id<-as.factor(df$id)

Comment: @user85727 Could you put it as another example in the question? It's hard to copy-paste from your comment.

Comment: not sure that any(diff(w) > 2L) works in general, may need to be any(diff(w) > 1L)

Comment: @user85727 If it's switched to 1, then id 4 is also identified as true, but you said that it should be false so I inferred the different threshold. Generally, if you include desired output and the rules behind it in a very explicit way in a question, this sort of confusion can often be avoided.

Comment: your code is giving me Error: invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment: > library(dplyr)
> 
> df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(x = {
+     w = which(num == 2)
+     length(w) > 1L && any(diff(w) > 2L) 
+ })

Comment: @user85727 Hm. I'm not sure, but it looks like, based on that error, you have copied the code wrong so that it has extra `+` symbols in it..? Alternately, it could be some conflict between dplyr and something else you have loaded, which is fairly common with dplyr.

Comment: Thanks, it works, was a conflict issue. However, I've never seen that syntax in "summarise" before....? can you point to a reference?

Comment: @user85727 The documentation is at `?summarise`. If you go through a dplyr tutorial, you will see that it is central to the package. I brought up dplyr in the answer because you tagged it in the question, but I don't really recommend the package.